# What is "topology in dimension 3.5"?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, manifolds, 4-manifolds

I've noticed a couple of conference titles which reference something called 
"topology in dimension 3.5," such as [this one](http://math.rice.edu/NewsEvents/Conferences/TopologyConference2016/index.html) and [this one](https://sites.google.com/sjsu.edu/thompscharbyfest/home). This subject seems quite mysterious to me — it looks like it's part of geometric topology, but I'm guessing it's not about 3.5-dimensional manifolds, so what kinds of things are studied in 3.5-dimensional topology?

Comment: The conference memoralizing Tim Cochran you reference was so named because Tim’s research focused on knot concordance, which studies how 3-dimensional objects (knots) interact with 4-manifolds.

Comment: Looking at abstracts, it sounds like just a joke, to mean relations between 3-dim and 4-dim topology.

Comment: Indeed, the reference to "3.5" is a joke, meant to imply that someone spends half their time on 3 dimensions, and half on 4 dimensions, so on average spends their time thinking about 3.5 dimensions. Moreover, for the conference for Thompson, Scharlemann and Kirby, Thompson is principally known for studying 3 dimensional manifolds, Scharlemann 3 & 4, and Kirby 4 dimensions (although this is not strictly true). Moreover, they are turning 60, 70 and 80 this year, so 20 x the "dimensions". Even though I'm on the organizing committee, I don't claim responsibility for the conference title.

Comment: @IanAgol AndyPutman YCor thank you all for the answers! I guess something mixing 3- and 4-dimensional topology was probably the most reasonable definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cw answer: As mentioned in the comments, this just refers to the relations between 3-dimensional and 4-dimensional topology.